# Algorithm to compare complexity classes

Tags: computational-complexity

Sometimes sophisticated algorithms have very complicated looking expressions for the run time complexity which got me to wondering.

Let $F$ be the set of functions containing, constant functions, polynomial functions, the exponential function, the log function, and closed over composition.

Is there an algorithm that can compare the big $\mathcal{O}$ complexity of two arbitrary functions $f_1,f_2 \in F$ and determine if $\mathcal{O}(f_1) < \mathcal{O}(f_2)$

Comment: Nope. Complexity Theory wouldn't be a field otherwise.

Comment: @DonThousand I'm not so sure - the OP is looking specifically about comparing growth rates within a rather restricted class of functions, so I think there's a decent possibility of such an algorithm.

Comment: There are methods, just compare the growth rates of $f_1$ and $f_2$.